# How to hide the surrounding blue border of html5 audio controls?

Tags: html, html5-audio

[image]

As you can see from the picture, when I click the html5 audio control, there's blue border surrounding.

How can I remove this blue border?

Comment: css `outline: none` may solve this issue. Do you try it ?

Answer (score 6):

```
audio:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please **edit** your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Kinda seems like this answer is almost self-documenting to me.